# operations on lists using zip or array

Tags: python, list, numpy, sum

I am wondering what is the best to do if I want to sum the elements (elements by elements) of two lists named l1 and l2:

```
l3 =  [i + j for i, j in zip(l1,l2)]
```

or converting the lists as arrays and do a simple sum

```
from numpy import array
l3 = list(array(l1) + array(l2))
```

Comment: Best in what? Performance? Code clarity?

Comment: numpy will almost certainly be the faster way

Comment: I was rather thinking in term of speed and memory usage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably depends on how big the lists are.

`numpy` is designed for efficient operations on large sets of data, but introduces some constant overhead because it's not part of native Python.

Also, if you're going for performance, [`itertools.izip`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) may give you better speed.

---

For just random lists, I'd probably go with `[i+j for i,j in izip(l1, l2)]` due to simplicity/readability, assuming they aren't large enough to bring significant performance into question.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
from operator import add
map(add, list1, list2)
```

This uses the potentially optimised `operator.add` and avoids using `zip`/`izip` which will truncate input to the shortest sequence allowing errors to fail silently - while `map` (well `operator.add`) will raise an exception.

Probably the best you can do in pure Python...

Comment: That is, not considering numpy

Comment: @jamylak That's why I mentioned "in pure Python"

Comment: I was just clarifying my comment, your answer is fine. I didn't +1 this because I didn't like how it the least readable but it could be useful in some case